# What does this extra argument for a VLDR instruction mean?

Tags: assembly, arm

Working with ASM code, bit I don't understand what does is the difference between these lines?

```
VLDR            S0, [R5]
VLDR            S2, [R5,#4]
```

What is the meaning of **#4**?

Comment: take a look at this post: [What do the following ARM instructions mean?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/what-do-the-following-arm-instructions-mean?rq=1) and [how to load a constant from memory](https://community.arm.com/processors/b/blog/posts/how-to-load-constants-in-assembly-for-arm-architecture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
VLDR            S0, [R5]
```

Load single-precision extension register `S0`. R5 is the ARM register with the base address for the transfer.

```
VLDR            S2, [R5,#4]
```

Load single-precision extension register `S2`. R5 is the ARM register with the base address for the transfer; however we will be adding the numeric offset (`#4`) to the base address `R5` to get the address used for the transfer.